# React Carousel with text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, reactstrap, react-multi-carousel

I am using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel in one of my react project and I have implemented it and it works fine.

I am now in the need to implement the text (legend) over the carousel exactly like https://codesandbox.io/s/lp602ljjj7 which uses another package but I need that scenario and not that package because my need is different (Using nextjs so multi-carousel supports ssr and hence using it).

My only need is need to know how to implement the legend text over the carousel image using `react-multi-carousel`.

My code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-playground-bt3v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the structure of the return statement to the following structure.

Then you can store the value of the legend in the image array and pass the value to the `p` tag

```
const Simple = ({ deviceType }) => {
  return (
    <Carousel
      ssr
      partialVisbile
      deviceType={deviceType}
      itemClass="image-item"
      responsive={responsive}
    >
      {images.slice(0, 5).map((image, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} style={{ position: "relative" }}>
            <img
              draggable={false}
              alt="text"
              style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
              src={image}
            />
            <p
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: "50%",
                bottom: 0,
                color: "white",
                transform: " translateX(-50%)"
              }}
            >
              Legend:{index}.
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Carousel>
  );
};

export default Simple;
```

Comment: Thanks for your cleaner solution.. Can you help me here ??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638007/display-menu-items-in-next-view-using-reactjs

Comment: Also I would like to know whether the exact behaviour mentioned in my question can be achieved using reactstrap?? For which also I have question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59646923/reactjs-slick-slide

Answer (score -1):

**[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-playground-8qqsh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

You should change array structure like below.

```
const images = [
    {
        image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549989476-69a92fa57c36?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60",
        text: "First image",
    }
];
```

Then inside loop just add text and style it our way!

```
const Simple = ({ deviceType }) => {
    return (
        <Carousel
            ssr
            partialVisbile
            deviceType={deviceType}
            itemClass="image-item"
            responsive={responsive}
        >
            {images.map(image => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <img
                            draggable={false}
                            alt="text"
                            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                            src={image.image}
                        />
                        {/* Have to style so this should see over the image */}
                        <span>{image.text}</span>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </Carousel>
    );
};
```

Comment: Can you create codesandbox example and post the link in answer?

Comment: see https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-playground-8qqsh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark